# jQuery put a tag under another tag

Tags: jquery

I have this codes in HTML

```
<input type="text" id="autoComplete">
```

I want add div#autoCompleteContainer tag under #autoComplete like other autoComplete suggestions tags

I use this to append div#autoCompleteContainer  tag to the document

```
$('body').append('<div id="autoCompleteContainer">' + ' ' + '</div>');
```

but I don't how to set div#autoCompleteContainer under #autoComplete like this 
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrJOJ.jpg)

Comment: Why don't you use [jQuery Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: @Jagjeet Singh because I think mine is more beautiful

Comment: If your question is answered, mark the correct answer. If not, ask in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Use [$.insertAfter](https://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/):

```js
var autoComplete = $('#autoComplete');

$('<div id="autoCompleteContainer">Successfully inserted!</div>').insertAfter(autoComplete);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="autoComplete">
<p>Just so you see it's between this and the input.</p>
```